# How to run javascript and fetch a value of hidden variable in page source using XCUITest?

Tags: uiwebview, automated-tests, xcode-ui-testing

I'm new to this iOS world but quite excited to use XCUITest to automate my iOS webView application. I'm trying to figure out as to how can i run javascript from my XCTest for webView application and fetch the value of the hidden variable. 
For e.g. my app has webView and it's page source contains the following elements
`<input type="hidden" name="demo" value="test">`

I've got the handle of the webView using the following:

```
let webViewQury:XCUIElementQuery = app.descendantsMatchingType(.WebView)
let webview = webViewQury.elementAtIndex(0)
```

but i'm not sure as to how can run javascript to get the value of the element mentioned above i.e. "demo". I know we can use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` but this method is applicable for `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, the answer is `you can't`. Indeed, you cannot access your app code while UI Testing:

> UI testing exercises your app's UI in the same way that users do
>   without access to your app's internal methods, functions, and
>   variables. This enables your tests to see the app the same way a user
>   does, exposing UI problems that users encounter.
>
> Your test code runs as a separate process, synthesizing events that UI
>   in your app responds to.

(Source: [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/09-ui_testing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH13-SW1))

You only can interact with your app by using [XCUIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuiapplication) and [XCUIElement](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuielement). They do not allow you to do what you want.

You really should concider UI Testing as a way to act as a user on your application. You will never ask to a user `do my UIWebView contains this source code?`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, i agree that we will never ask a user to do the operation that i've mentioned but since my app was interacting with APIs, i had to post to those APIs using the value of a hidden variable in page source. Once i make an API call, i will get value in return which i need to fill in UI text field. I was able to do this android using espresso but unfortunately there is no way to figure this out in XCUITest. What would you recommend to automate such step?

Comment: There is no way to do so, since you cannot access to your UIWebView object or to its content.

Comment: Right! So as an alternative we have created a debug only build where we expose the value of the hidden variable on UI so that XCUITest can operate on it. Thanks Julien for your time. Closing this thread

Comment: Julien's answer was correct; you should mark it as such. :)